# Hadoop 'grep' example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop 'grep' example (that comes with the Hadoop package) what is the group parameter.Can you give me an example for that.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you can you add more information (or atleast include a link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't run this example and am pulling answering after just looking at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Grep

The CLI call is: `bin/hadoop org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep <indir> <outdir> <regex> [<group>]` and you want to know about `<group>`.

I suspect this is *grouping* in regex. (random link - http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html)

As noted on the Hadoop Grep link

> The command works different than the
>   Unix grep call: it doesn't display the
>   complete matching line, but only the
>   matching string

What I take from this is that if you specify the `<group>` value (a number) it will output only the value for that group.

For an example (pulling from the Group link)

> **input:**   aba
>   **regex:** (a(b)*)+
>   **group 0:** aba
>   **group 1:** a
>   **group 2:** b

If the value for `<group>` is `1` then the result would be `a`. Group 0 is the full match, not the original string, In this case it just happens to be the same.

hth